# How do to I send my select box value to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, select, onchange

I have a random amount of select boxes generated by javascript, all containing the same options. Now I wish to have a "master-selectbox" which sets the value for each and every one of them.

Currently I have `<select id="changeKlas" onChange="javascript:changeClass(this.parentNode, getElementById(changeKlas))">`

At the javascript I've gotten as far as to find each and every select box and I already know how to set the value but the value is not being send to javascript.

On each attempt I have made the `getElementById(changeKlas)` is null.  How can I fix this so I can get the text and value of the selected textbox in the given select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the id: `[...], document.getElementById('changeKlas')` -- notice the single quote, double quote needs to be escaped because of the outer one from `onChange`. Also, notice that `getElementById` belongs to `document`

Comment: So simpel.. thank you very much.  ps, The document isn't needed. I have it working without

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<select id="changeKlas" onChange="changeClass(this)">
```

And in your JavaScript, this will be transformed to `document.getElementById(changeKlas)`

Comment: also works. (adding extra text to fill the required amount of characters)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="changeKlas" onChange="changeClass();">
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
</select>

<script>
function changeClass()
{
 var changeKlas = document.getElementById('changeKlas').value;
alert(changeKlas);
}
</script>
```

// On change It will alert the SELECTED VALUE